# How to get the field names of the table in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I am a complete newbie in CakePHP. I want to read the field names of the table in the controller.

I want the controller to **list all the field names in the table**. How do I do that?

Comment: Could you give us more context? Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @JohnP, for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 26):

Use the following snippet to get an array of the field names (replace "YourModel" with the name of your model):

```
array_keys($this->YourModel->getColumnTypes());
```

Answer (score 16):

as simple as
$this->Model->schema()

Answer (score 6):

For CakePHP 3.x

**$this->Model->schema()** - Returns the Schema object.

**$this->Model->schema()->columns()** - Returns all of the columns in the table in an array.